# SQL Subquery and Join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

```
SELECT
session.session_id as ID,
session.anum,
student.first,
student.last,
session.why,
session.studentcomments,
session.aidyear,
support.counselorcomments
FROM student
INNER JOIN session ON student.anum = session.anum
LEFT JOIN support ON session.session_id = support.session_id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT session_id, cid, starttime FROM support ORDER BY starttime asc limit 1
) 
AS timing ON timing.session_id = session.session_id 
WHERE session.status NOT IN (0,2);
```

This returns me with this value :

```
+-----+-----------+---------+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+-------------------+
| ID  | anum      | first   | last    | why          | studentcomments | aidyear | counselorcomments |
+-----+-----------+---------+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+-------------------+
| 175 | A00000000 | rixhers | ajazi   | Appeal       |                 | 12-13   | NULL              |
| 176 | B00000000 | Testing | thisout | Tap Question |                 | 12-13   | omg!              |
| 176 | B00000000 | Testing | thisout | Tap Question |                 | 12-13   | Jesus!!           |
+-----+-----------+---------+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I do not want to have both ID's of 176 there, I want the most recently added one (that is why i use order by starttime asc limit 1 on my subquerys). Is there any way I can get this to work with the means that I have set forward now?

Edit Number 1 :

```
mysql> SELECT  session.session_id as ID,
    ->         session.anum,
    ->         student.first,
    ->         student.last,
    ->         session.why,
    ->         session.studentcomments,
    ->         session.aidyear,
    ->         support.counselorcomments
    -> FROM    student
    ->         INNER JOIN session 
    ->             ON student.anum = session.anum
    ->         LEFT JOIN support 
    ->             ON session.session_id = support.session_id
    ->         LEFT JOIN 
    ->         (
    ->             SELECT session_id, max(starttime) max_time
    ->             FROM support 
    ->             GROUP BY session_id
    ->         ) timing ON timing.session_id = support.session_id AND
    ->                     timing.max_time = support.starttime
    -> WHERE   session.status IN (0,2);
+-----+-----------+---------+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+-------------------+
| ID  | anum      | first   | last    | why          | studentcomments | aidyear | counselorcomments |
+-----+-----------+---------+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+-------------------+
| 175 | A00000000 | rixhers | ajazi   | Appeal       |                 | 12-13   | NULL              |
| 176 | B00000000 | Testing | thisout | Tap Question |                 | 12-13   | omg!              |
| 176 | B00000000 | Testing | thisout | Tap Question |                 | 12-13   | Jesus!!           |
+-----+-----------+---------+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Did not have the desired effect either anything else? Should my support.starttime be a index the database so timing.starttime = support.starttime will work?

Edit 2 :

```
mysql> SELECT session_id,
    -> max(starttime) max_time FROM support
    -> GROUP BY session_id;
+------------+---------------------+
| session_id | max_time            |
+------------+---------------------+
|        176 | 2013-01-28 07:44:17 |
+------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Edit 3 :

```
mysql> SELECT session_id, cid, starttime FROM support;
+------------+-----+---------------------+
| session_id | cid | starttime           |
+------------+-----+---------------------+
|        176 |   1 | 2013-01-28 07:44:08 |
|        176 |   2 | 2013-01-28 07:44:17 |
+------------+-----+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT : works now, thank you JQ for trying to help!

and thank you to sgeddes for the answer!

```
mysql> SELECT  DISTINCT session.session_id as id,
    ->         session.anum,
    ->         student.first,
    ->         student.last,
    ->         session.why,
    ->         session.studentcomments,
    ->         session.aidyear,
    ->         support.counselorcomments
    -> FROM    student
    ->         INNER JOIN session 
    ->             ON student.anum = session.anum
    ->         LEFT JOIN support 
    ->             ON session.session_id = support.session_id
    ->         LEFT JOIN support support2
    ->             ON support.session_id = support2.session_id
    ->                 AND support.starttime < support2.starttime
    -> WHERE   session.status IN (0,2) 
    ->     AND support2.session_id IS NULL;
+-----+-----------+---------+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+
| id  | anum      | first   | last    | why          | studentcomments | aidyear | counselorcomments  |
+-----+-----------+---------+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+
| 175 | A00000000 | rixhers | ajazi   | Appeal       |                 | 12-13   | yo please help me! |
| 176 | B00000000 | Testing | thisout | Tap Question |                 | 12-13   | Jesus!!            |
| 177 | C00000000 | ufufu   | ufufjn  | Appeal       |                 | 12-13   | NULL               |
+-----+-----------+---------+---------+--------------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Edit 4: doesnt change the table, I just have a historic view available for when i am running reports. and then I needed a up to date current view for now.

```
mysql> SELECT session_id, cid, counselorcomments starttime FROM support;
+------------+-----+-------------------+
| session_id | cid | starttime         |
+------------+-----+-------------------+
|        175 |   4 | NULL              |
|        175 |   5 | help!             |
|        175 |   7 | please need help! |
|        176 |   1 | omg!              |
|        176 |   2 | Jesus!!           |
|        177 |   1 | ihgggwhb          |
+------------+-----+-------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Your the second person to tell look at DISTINCT. I brought this up to my professor and he told me to look towards a sub-query.

Comment: Distinct is usually a crutch for when you can't figure out the proper filter conditions.

Comment: Using distinct won't work anyway because the counsellor comments are different.

Comment: Gotta be missing something -- DISTINCT won't change 175 and 176...  Glad it's "working" though -- I think it's the INNER JOIN that's fixing it.  Good luck!

Comment: look at edit 4, its working, its maintaining historic data, and the current value, and the student queue is only displaying current data. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative to using a subquery.  You could just join on the table again. Something like this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT session.session_id as ID,
        session.anum,
        student.first,
        student.last,
        session.why,
        session.studentcomments,
        session.aidyear,
        support.counselorcomments
FROM    student
        INNER JOIN session 
            ON student.anum = session.anum
        INNER JOIN support 
            ON session.session_id = support.session_id
        LEFT JOIN support support2
            ON support.session_id = support2.session_id
                AND support.starttime < support2.starttime
WHERE   session.status NOT IN (0,2) 
    AND support2.session_id IS NULL
```

Both approaches should produce the same results.

Good luck.

Comment: im sorry for my ignorance but what exactly is support2?

Comment: No problem -- It's a way of joining the same table on itself -- it will help eliminate duplicate rows by using support.starttime < support2.starttime -- give it a try and let me know how it works.  Possibly we're not understanding your question though since this should produce the same results as @JW -- just an alternative.

Comment: More simplified -- "support2" is an alias for the 2nd "support" table :)

Comment: @RaGe10940 -- Your problem is you're using a LEFT JOIN -- this will return both records (hence the NULL value)...  If you always want the max, just change LEFT to INNER.

Comment: support2 is an alias that was used to call the support table more than once in the same query.  This approach has a problem.  Because there is a left join to support2 and it is constrained in the where clause, the left join becomes an inner join which is not what you want.  Normally you simply move that constraint to the join, but in this case that wouldn't work because it's looking for a null value in what might be the primary key field.  Keep looking at subqueries.

Comment: @DanBracuk -- I think the OP actually might want an INNER JOIN (although I see what you're saying about 2 LEFT JOINs) -- I've updated my answer.  OP wants max record, therefore removing record 175 if I'm not mistaken...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  session.session_id as ID,
        session.anum,
        student.first,
        student.last,
        session.why,
        session.studentcomments,
        session.aidyear,
        support.counselorcomments
FROM    student
        INNER JOIN session 
            ON student.anum = session.anum
        INNER JOIN support 
            ON session.session_id = support.session_id
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT session_id, max(starttime) max_time
            FROM support 
            GROUP BY session_id
        ) timing ON timing.session_id = support.session_id AND
                    timing.max_time = support.starttime
WHERE   session.status NOT IN (0,2);
```

Comment: Updated OP still undesired result set

Comment: can you output the `starttime` of the two records?

Comment: updated, that output is the same as my original output using SELECT session_id, cid, starttime FROM support ORDER BY starttime asc limit 1

Comment: are the two records on 176 have the same starttime of `2013-01-28 07:44:17`? do you have any auto_incrementing fields on table `support`?

Comment: if yes then you can modify it by getting the maximum auto_incremented id, `LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT session_id, max(autoID) max_ID
            FROM support 
            GROUP BY session_id
        ) timing ON timing.session_id = support.session_id AND
                    timing.max_ID = support.autoID`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT session_id, max(cid) max_ID
            FROM support 
            GROUP BY session_id
        ) timing ON timing.session_id = support.session_id AND
                    timing.max_ID = support.cid`

Comment: the CID isn't auto increment each employee gets a ID and i have that in a table. it just so happens to be 1 then 2, it could possibly be employee 8 first, then employee 2 second. The order has to work with the timings, not the session_id,cid

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23743/discussion-between-jw-and-rage10940)